# Why isn't my web page closing after the video?

Tags: javascript, html, exit

It is pretty simple what I am trying to accomplish, but I think my website hates me. It is currently live at;
https://www.eves.website/eve_6.html

except it doesn't close the webpage after the video has finished. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
    self.close();   
  }); 
});
</script>
</head>
  <body>

<video id="myVideo" style="margin-left:-10px; margin-top:-10px;" width="105%" height="105%" autoplay>
  <source src="images/death.mp4" autoplay="true" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you open your website? If you are opening by entering the URL in a new tab, it **cannot** be closed using JavaScript. The way you have put, the script has a requirement that the page to be closed, **cannot** be the original page.

It must be opened as a new window using **JavaScript**. If you wish to close a page that has been posted via form, the page must first have still been opened in a separate window using **JavaScript**.

**From MDN for [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close#Closing_the_current_window):**

> In the past, when you called the `window` object's `close()` method directly, rather than calling `close()` on a `window` **instance**, the browser closed the frontmost window, whether your script created that window or not. This is no longer the case; for security reasons, scripts are no longer allowed to close windows they didn't open. (Firefox 46.0.1: scripts can not close windows, they had not opened).

Comment: It is in a series of sripts, so first is www.eves.website, than the user is redirect to  www.eves.website/eve_1.html, than www.eves.website/eve_2.html etc etc

Comment: So there is nothing to do to make it close after the video has played?

Comment: @B.Ashcroft No. Not possible. I have added a reference from MDN: In the past, when you called the `window` object's `close()` method directly, rather than calling `close()` on a `window` **instance**, the browser closed the frontmost window, whether your script created that window or not. This is no longer the case; for security reasons, scripts are no longer allowed to close windows they didn't open. (Firefox 46.0.1: scripts can not close windows, they had not opened).

Comment: @Ashcroft how do you open your video site? do you use window.open() from other page to open the video page? if yes then you can use window.close()

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the site with the script then you can use this

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',function(){

       window.close();

  }, false);
```